# What really happens when Time Machine is "cleaning up"?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I've noticed that "cleaning up" in Time Machine seems to take two, three, more times as long as the actual backup.  Since copying a single large file could take several seconds, while deleting one takes milliseconds, what sort of cleanup is actually happening?

Does it copy the files and then search for unchanged files to replace with hard links?  That would be ridiculously inefficient.

[One answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332181/in-timemachine-what-happens-during-the-clean-up-phase) lists three things it does (which is the same as what I assumed it does) but doesn’t explain why it takes so long.

Comment: Deleting many small files still takes a while

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate to the linked question and edited the answer to provide some detail as to why it takes so long.